# SQL group values for one column by another column

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

Is there some kind of "aggregate" function in SQL that just turns values into a list? An example might be a table of the form:

```
| game_id | player | score |
|---------|--------|-------|
|   1     | fred   | 2     |
|   1     | tom    | 1     |
|   2     | fred   | 3     |
|   2     | tom    | 4     |
```

What I would like returned is a table that looks like this:

```
| player | scores |
|--------|--------|
|   fred | 2, 3   | 
|   tom  | 1, 4   |
```

The command might look something like:
`SELECT player, listify(score) FROM games GROUP BY player;`

Comment: Tag you question with the database you are using.  Better yet, you can just Google "<your database> group_concat".  `group_concat()` is the function in MySQL and there are lots of answers to questions about how to get similar functionality in other databases.

Comment: The answer completely depends on the database you are using.  Are you using MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, or something else?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Tim and Gordon. The Postgres function I'm looking for is `array_agg`. The full query in this case looks like this:

```
SELECT player, array_to_string(array_agg(score), ',') AS scores FROM games GROUP BY player;
```

`array_agg` puts all the scores into an array, and you have to convert them to a string to be able to return them in a SELECT statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string_agg` so then you'll not need to call 2 different functions `array_agg` and `array_to_string`.

```sql
SELECT player, string_agg(score::text, ',') AS scores FROM games GROUP BY player;
```

[**STRING_AGG()**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html)

[**Live Demo**](https://rextester.com/WVZW50004)